# Leaky shower arm

Tags: plumbing

[image][image]

At the “V” in this connection, is a tightening toggle. It’s as tight as possible, but continues to leak. What to do?
Thanks

Comment: Can you disassemble it and check for bad washers or "o" rings?

Comment: +1, there is likely an "O" ring or something that makes the seal, it is likely old, deteriorated, deformed etc. Take it apart and take a look.